# How to control Copy & Paste popup position of UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

Is it possible to control the `Paste` popup position of `UITextField`, say, above or below the `UITextField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i believe that the method you are looking for is `setTargetRect:inView:`. You can read more about it in the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIMenuController/setTargetRect%3ainView%3a).

Here is some general code from [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/AddingCustomEditMenuItems/AddingCustomEditMenuItems.html)

```
UIMenuController *theMenu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
CGRect selectionRect = CGRectMake (currentSelection.x, currentSelection.y, SIDE, SIDE);
[theMenu setTargetRect:selectionRect inView:self];
[theMenu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```